# Heroku Deployment and DB Migration Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple skeleton Rails 3.0.5 (and Ruby 1.9.2) app to Heroku, but encounter the same error when I open the website and when I try to migrate the db. I created the Heroku app with `heroku create --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2`. Everything works locally.

```
Code: https://github.com/curiousyogurt/SEE
 App: http://stormy-ice-778.heroku.com/
```

1. When going to the website, I get an "Application Error"; in the logs, I get the following error (followed by lots of other information):

   > 2011-03-20T17:25:31-07:00 app[web.1]: /app/cfde9dd3-c394-45fb-a0ef-72a753e83909/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in 'method_missing': undefined method `action' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000001d398d8> (NoMethodError)
   >
   > Stack Trace: gist.github.com/878866
2. When doing `heroku rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

   > rake aborted!
   >   undefined method 'action' for #
   >   /app/44666f97-ad08-444e-9f39-9ca7eb8fdc93/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing'
   >
   > Stack Trace: gist.github.com/878870

Here is my Gemfile (non-production parts removed):

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise',
              :branch => 'master'
gem 'omniauth'
```

I'm not sure where to go next in trying to track down this problem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you list a little more of the stack trace?

Comment: Sure thing. Here it is: gist.github.com/878866 (the stack trace for #1 above); and https://gist.github.com/878870 (the stack trace for #2 above).

Comment: One more! How about the contents of `config/environments/production.rb`? The stack trace points to a problem in that file.

Comment: That fixed it.  Here is the production.rb: https://gist.github.com/878896 ... and it turns out that by commenting out `config.action.mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'stormy-ice-778.heroku.com' }`, I was able to solve the problem.  I'm not really sure why it caused the problem; any thoughts?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.action.mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'stormy-ice-778.heroku.com' }
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb` should be

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'stormy-ice-778.heroku.com' }
```

(change `action.mailer` to `action_mailer`).

Comment: Thank you for solving this; I really appreciate it.